# How to build Aroon Indicator with AnyChart?

Tags: stock, indicator, anychart

I’m trying to migrate from AnyChart Stock Flash to HTML5 version, but there is no Aroon indicator at the moment.
I see there is a [custom indicator](http://docs.anychart.com/7.9.0/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Custom_Indicators) option in docs, but I have no idea how to build Aroon on it. Can anyone provide me some help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [computer](http://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.data.TableComputer) object using [.createComputer()](http://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.data.Table#createComputer) method, like

```
  var aroonCalculator = dataTable.createComputer(mapping);
```

and calculate Aroon indicator values.

The complete example is available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qsky9va5/1/

The sample is using AnyChart Stock 7 and all data is prepared for AnyChart Stock HTML5 version. All information about how to create custom indicators you can find here:
http://docs.anychart.com/7.9.0/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Custom_Indicators

All other technical questions, just let us know via [support@anychart.com](http://support@anychart.com) and we will be happy to help.